# Approximation of non-analytic function

Tags: taylor-expansion, analyticity, approximation-theory

I have a function which is of the form
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1 - x^{1/2} + x - x^{3/2} + \ldots}{1+x^{1/2} - x + x^{3/2} - \ldots}.
\end{equation}
Intuitively, I would assume that for small $x$, it holds
\begin{equation}
f(x) \approx \frac{1-x^{1/2}}{1+x^{1/2}}
\end{equation}
and then, furthermore, 
\begin{equation}
f(x) \approx 1 - a x^{1/2} + \ldots 
\end{equation}
where $a$ is some factor. My question is: How can I determine $a$ and the range of $x$ for which this approximation is valid? Obviously, I cannot use a Taylor approximation since $f$ is not analytic and the derivative diverges in the origin.

Let me point out that I am not so much interested in the specific example above, which I have just invented. Much rather, I would like to know what is the general theory and methods behind this type of fractional functions.

Comment: Actually, I have a somewhat heuristic explanation to answer my second approximation: simply multiply numerator and denominator by (1-x^{1/2}). This way, the square root drops out in the denominator and some sort of first order Taylor approximation can be calculated. This is, however, very heuristic. I'd rather now the theory behind this type of problems.

Comment: i was too fast sorry

Comment: as a quick guess i would say the approximation holds as long as $ax^{1/2}$ is bigger then the next order contribution...so now it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to treat this particular sort of problem.  It is an analytic function of, say, $z$, where $z=x^{1/2}$.

Comment: I agree, but what if, for instance, I have a function such as $\frac{1 + x^{1/7} - x^{2/5}}{1 - x^{1/9} + x^{3/13}}$. Then this idea does not apply.

Comment: Least common denominator.

Comment: agreed, this solves the problem (as long as all exponents are rational, which is fairly general).

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the numerator, is 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x^{1/2})^k = \frac{1}{1 + x^{1/2}}, \quad |x| <  1 $$
and the denominator equals 
$$ 2 -\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x^{1/2})^k = 2 - \frac 1{1 + x^{1/2}} $$
Hence 
\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= \frac{\frac 1{1 + x^{1/2}}}{\frac{2(1 + x^{1/2}) - 1}{1 + x^{1/2}}}\\
   &= \frac 1{2(1 + x^{1/2}) - 1}\\
   &= \frac 1{1 + 2x^{1/2}}\\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-2x^{1/2})^k\\
   &= 1 - 2x^{1/2} + 4x \mp \cdots
\end{align*}
That is, $a = 2$ seems like a good choice.

---

Addendum: If we write $f$ as $g(\sqrt x)$ with 
$$ g(y) = \frac{1 - y + y^2 \mp}{1 + y - y^2 \pm } $$
then we can Taylor expand $g$ nicely, giving 
$$ g(y) = 1 - 2y + 4y^2 \mp $$
and hence
$$ f(x) = 1 - 2x^{1/2} + 4x \mp $$
and the range of convergence can be obtained by that of $g$.

Comment: I like your solution, it is very elegant. However, it seems to be somewhat specific to the above example. What if the ratio is in fractional powers but less regular than the problem I have just invented for simplicity. In that case, there is no closed form of the series and the solution does not apply.

Comment: I am looking more for the branch of mathematical theory that treats this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest $$\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\approx 1-2\sqrt{x}$$

because of $(1+\sqrt{x})(1-2\sqrt{x})=1-\sqrt{x}-2x$